# React Native WebView ios Native module cannot be null

Tags: react-native

We are building a LibGdx app, with a react native frontend.  We are on React Native 0.56 .  I recently added a WebView to display help videos from youtube.

```
{this.props.appData.showLearningVideos ?
                <View style={styles.WebViewContainer}>
                    <WebView
                        useWebKit={true}
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        domStorageEnabled={true}
                        startInLoadingState={true}
                        style={{flex: 1, margin: 0, padding: 0}}
                        source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ this.state.selectedVideo +'?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0'}}
                    />
                    {this.state.showVideoMenu?
                    <View style={styles.videoList}>
                        <FlatList
                            scrollEnabled = {false}
                            data={this.state.videoList}
                            renderItem={({item}) =>
                                <View style={styles.menuItem}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            this.setState({selectedVideo: item.YTId, showVideoMenu: false});
                                        }}>
                                        <Text style={styles.menuText}>{item.label}</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>

                            }
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.menuItem}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.props.showLearningVideo(false);
                                }}>
                                <Text style={styles.menuText}>Exit</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View> :
                    <View style={styles.videoMenu}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => {
                                this.setState({showVideoMenu: true});;
                            }}>
                            <Icon name="menu"
                                  size={25}
                                  color="#7C7C7C"/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>}
                </View>:null}
```

The WebView works like a charm on Android, but ios is giving me the error: Native module cannot be null

[ios debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXgAx.png)

Comment: I met this issue too. Do you resolve it?

Comment: After I ran Xcode updates, cleared my node modules, reran npm install, and reran pod update and pod install, cleaned and rebuilt the project, it seemed to resolve itself.

Comment: I tried your method, and still have same error. I am on 0.57.3.

Comment: React-native Webview component is being extracted to https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview.